# how is datacontractserializer performance 10% better than xmlserializer?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

I came across this in many articles recently and they didnt explain anything about this. 
How is datacontractserializer performance 10% better ? Is this 10% figure mentioned by Microsoft anywhere ?

Can anyone tell me on what parameters is this figure based on, does this depend on the size of the object also. And will xmlserializer perform 10% worse in every scenario ?

Comment: why don't you measure it yourself and let us all know

Comment: You might also want to look at the differences in capabilities of the two - the difference may give you a clue.

Comment: Well, here are some claims: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/07/10/comparing-the-performance-of-net-serializers.aspx - however, in a lot of my tests I've seen it go either way (one or the other faster, depending on the scenario). Frankly, if performance was a key concern I wouldn't be using xml in the first place...